# How to Update Default Compute Zone and Region of Configurations in Google Cloud Shell - CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, configuration, gcloud

I have multiple `configurations` created via the `gcloud init` command. It does not give me the option to set a Default Compute Region or a Default Compute Zone.

When I run, `gcloud config configurations list`, the default zone and region are empty.

[image]

`gcloud config configurations ...` only provides following commands. (No Update command)

- activate
- create
- delete
- describe
- list

Can't I set a default region and zone when initializing a configuration? If no, how can I update certain fields of a gcloud configuration? Eg: `COMPUTE_DEFAULT_ZONE` or `COMPUTE_DEFAULT_REGION`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an associated gcloud command called [gcloud config set](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set) that is used to set/update properties in the currently active configuration.  What this means is that you can create a configuration, activate it and then perform `gcloud config set` commands to change the settings.  Looking at the docs, both `compute region` and `compute zone` are documented as being present to set the default region and default zone respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Kolban mentioned if you look at the set configs you will find:

```
gcloud config set compute/zone [YOUR ZONE NAME HERE]
```

EXAMPLE: (gcloud config set compute/zone asia-east1-b)

Additionally, I like to also set the region as well at the same time

```
gcloud config set compute/region [YOUR REGION NAME HERE]
```

EXAMPLE: (gcloud config set compute/region asia-east1)